# Query works in Oracle by not in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

This query works in Oracle:

```
select count(city) - count (distinct city) from station;
```

But doesn't work in MySQL. What's the MySQL equivalent of this query? At the risk of pointing out obvious, this query returns the 'difference' between 'total no. of cities' on the station table and number of distinct cities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work just fine if you remove space after second `count`

```sql
select count(city) - count(distinct city) from station;
                          ^
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a78bc/2)

> *To use the name as a function call in an expression, there must be no whitespace between the name and the following “(” parenthesis character.*

See [10.2.4 Function Name Parsing and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html)